# Can't delete .tgz files from script .sh

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, cron

there:
I have created a .sh script where i am creating a backup of the mongodb database.
When I create the backup everything is fine, the problem is that it does not eliminate the previous backups (i am eliminating every day the backup of 5 days ago).
Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUPS_DIR="/path/to/backups"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%d-%m-%y`
BACKUP_NAME="BACKUP-$TIMESTAMP"
mongodump --port 27017 --out $BACKUP_NAME
tar -zcvf $BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME.tgz $BACKUP_NAME
rm -rf $BACKUP_NAME
DATE_TO_DELETE=`date -d "$date -5 days" +%d-%m-%y`
FILE_TO_DELETE="BACKUP-$DATE_TO_DELETE"
rm -rf $FILE_TO_DELETE.tgz
```

When I run the script using
`./script_name.sh`
Everything working fine.
When I add it to crontab, it creates the backup but does not remove the backup from 5 days ago.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership of the file? How do you run the cron job and under which account? What error message do you get in your mail inbox? These are all very routine pedestrian troubleshooting steps. See the [Stack Overflow `cron` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) for more.

Comment: Is cron running the script in the same current working directory as you were using when you ran it directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your script to make sure you run your `rm -fr` from the proper directory.  Otherwise you could delete something you did not want to (Ask me how I know...!).  Crontab does not run the script from the directory it is located in.

So if you do:

```
cd $(which script_name.sh)
./script_name.sh
```

all is good.  But crontab does not do the `cd`.  Notice how your `tar` command works fine, since you specify `$BACKUP_DIR` in the destination file.

All this to say do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACKUPS_DIR="/path/to/backups"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%d-%m-%y`
BACKUP_NAME="BACKUP-$TIMESTAMP"
mongodump --port 27017 --out $BACKUP_NAME
tar -zcvf $BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME.tgz $BACKUP_NAME
rm -rf $BACKUP_NAME
DATE_TO_DELETE=`date -d "$date -5 days" +%d-%m-%y`
FILE_TO_DELETE="BACKUP-$DATE_TO_DELETE"

rm -rf $BACKUPS_DIR/$FILE_TO_DELETE.tgz
```

Another possibility would be to use `find` to remove all files older than 5 days in `$BACKUPS_DIR`.

Comment: This is!
I seem to have forgotten this little detail.
That's why it worked when you ran it manually and not when you ran it using cron.
Thank you!